# How to add ListView Items via Binding by Entity Framework / Linq

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq, xaml, binding

How to add `ListView` Items via binding by Entity Framework / Linq?

I got my `ListView` in the xaml with bindings here:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvw_Overview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" Margin="11,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="676">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Adresse" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding address}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is my code

```
Public Sub New()
    Initialize()
End Sub
Dim address As String
Dim items As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht)
Public Structure Uebersicht
    Private _address As String
    Public Property address As String
        Get
            Return _address
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _address = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure
Sub Initialize()
    InitializeComponent()
    fillListView()
End Sub
 Sub fillListView()
    Using container As New infrastrukturDB_TESTEntities1
        Dim mailAddressList = From tbl_unzustellbarAdressen In container.tbl_unzustellbarAdressen
        For Each mail In mailAddressList
            address = mail.unzustellbarMail.ToString()
            Try
                items.Add(New Uebersicht With {.address = address})
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error")
            End Try

        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

EDIT: tried the `ObserverableCollection` but now i got a `NullReferenceException`! 
If i debug, address got data.. not null

Comment: In C# you have the ObservableCollection which is what you link as itemSource on the .xaml. Not sure how its working in vb, but there should be something similar.

When you are not using the itemSource, you have to tell the Dispatcher to update the list with INotifyPropertyChanged, but again, I only know from C#, but maybe give you clues for searching a solution.

Comment: @Nekeniehl ObservableCollection is a .NET Framework class, and hence available in all supported languages.

Comment: @Raizzen "link as itemSource on the .xaml" means that you should bind the `ItemsSource` property of the ListView to an `ObservableCollection` of your item class. When you write `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding address}"` the item class is supposed to have a public property named `address`.

Comment: Like I said I do not have idea about vb, but always is a good time to learn things, thanks!

Comment: @Nekeniehl, Clemens ok ObserverableCollection.. gonna try it out

Comment: @Clemens i updated now the Code but i get NullReferenceException, even if theres data in address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are adding `strings` to the `ListView`, you should not bind to the `address` property but the source object itself:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvw_Overview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" Margin="11,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="676">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Adresse" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Edit:** You need to intialize the `ObservableCollection` before you can add items to it. And to be able to bind to the `ObservableCollection`, you must expose it as a property:

```
Public Sub New()
    Initialize()
End Sub

Dim address As String

Private _items As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht) = New ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht) 
Public Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht)
    Get
        Return _items
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht))
        _items = value
    End Set
End Property

Sub Initialize()
    InitializeComponent()
    DataContext = Me
    fillListView()
End Sub
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" Margin="11,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="676">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Adresse" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding address}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: ah u again.. xD but only with Binding in the xaml, how should the program know which variable to choose

Comment: ok now it works. i just get the wrong output in my gui but i think i can fix it by myself. iam sry for annoying u iam still learning :(

Comment: in that version ´Private _items As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht) = New ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht)´it underlines _items -> initializer for structur member is just valid for shared- member/constants

Comment: The setter should be Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht)).I edited my answer slightly.

Comment: it still underlines Private _items, btw what xaml is the right one? there are two in ur answer

Comment: It's because you changed your question. The second XAML snippet should be compatible with the VB.NET code in my answer. You need to change items.Add to _items.Add in your fillListView method.

Comment: fixed my method, but _items is still underlined

Comment: maybe it is because its still in the public structure Uebersicht? but if i comment the structure, there is no Uebersicht

Comment: fixed it.. changed private to shared and in the method _items -> Uebersicht._items but i got the feeling that the binding doesnt work, because if i start the programm the listbox is empty